# Is there a function to get the column names generated by `pivot_wider`?

Tags: r, pivot, tidyr

I am using `pivot_wider` with (potentially) multiple `names_from` and `values_from` columns. The resulting automatically generated column names are fine for my purposes.

My question is, is there a standalone function that will generate the vector of resultant column names given the `names_from` and `values_from` columns and the original tibble?

For instance, if I have `names_from=grp` where `grp` has levels `foo, bar, baz`, and `values_from=c("X", "Y")`, the resulting column names would be `X_foo, X_bar, X_baz, Y_foo, Y_bar, Y_baz`. Is there an easy way to get just those names?

Answer (score 1):

There is no standalone function, but you can make one, e.g. with `interaction`:

```r
f <- function(names_from, values_from){
  suppressWarnings(levels(interaction(values_from, unique(names_from), sep = "_")))
}

df <- data.frame(
  grp = rep(c("foo", "bar", "baz"), 5), 
  X = floor(runif(15) * 100),
  Y = floor(runif(15) * 100)
)
f(df$grp, c("X", "Y"))  
#[1] "X_bar" "Y_bar" "X_baz" "Y_baz" "X_foo" "Y_foo"
```

---

Or with `do.call`:

```r
do.call(paste, c(expand.grid(c("X", "Y"), unique(df$grp)), sep = "_"))
#[1] "X_bar" "Y_bar" "X_baz" "Y_baz" "X_foo" "Y_foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `expand.grid` for the combinations and then `paste` row-wise

```
apply(expand.grid(c("X", "Y"), c("foo", "bar", "baz")), 1, paste, collapse="_")
[1] "X_foo" "Y_foo" "X_bar" "Y_bar" "X_baz" "Y_baz"
```

Answer (score 0):

For your example you could generate them with

```
outer(c("X", "Y"), c("foo", "bar", "baz"), paste, sep = "_") |> 
  t() |>
  as.vector()
# [1] "X_foo" "X_bar" "X_baz" "Y_foo" "Y_bar" "Y_baz"
```

(Of course you can substitute `levels(your_data$grp)` for writing out the `c("foo", "bar", "baz")` part.)